# An urn problem involving conditional probabilities, law of total probability, and Bayes' rule

Tags: probability

I am working on the following problem. It is a variation of 3.14 from Ross' *A First Course in Probability*.

An urn initially contains 5 white and 7 black balls. Each time a ball is drawn, its color is noted and it is placed back in the urn along with two balls of the same color. Compute the probability that the first two balls selected are black given that the next two balls drawn are white.

My partial solutions is as follows: Let $B_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ ball drawn is black and $W_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ ball drawn is white. We are interested in computing $\mathbb{P} (B_1 B_2 | W_3 W_4)$. Using properties of conditional expectation, we can rewrite this as

$$\mathbb{P} (B_1, B_2 | W_3 ,W_4) = \frac{ \mathbb{P} (B_1, B_2, W_3, W_4)}{\mathbb{P} (W_3, W_4)} = \frac{ \mathbb{P} (W_4 | W_3, B_2, B_1) \mathbb{P} (W_3|B_2,B_1) \mathbb{P} (B_2 | B_1) \mathbb{P} (B_1) }{ \mathbb{P} (W_3, W_4)}.$$

The numerator is simple to compute. I'm having trouble computing the expression in the denominator. I initially wanted to use the Law of Total Probability to rewrite

$$ \mathbb{P} (W_3 ,W_4) = \mathbb{P} (W_3,W_4 | B_2 ,B_1) \mathbb{P} (B_2, B_1)  + \mathbb{P} (W_3,W_4 |  B_2, W_1) \mathbb{P} (B_2, W_1) + \mathbb{P} (W_3,W_4 | W_2 ,B_1) \mathbb{P} (W_2, B_1) + \mathbb{P} (W_3,W_4 | W_2 ,W_1) \mathbb{P} (W_2 ,W_1),$$

which we can compute using properties of conditional expectation.

Now we can compute

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} (W_3,W_4 | B_2, B_1) \mathbb{P} (B_2, B_1) &= \frac{ \mathbb{P} (B_1, B_2 ,W_3, W_4) \mathbb{P} (B_1 ,B_2) }{ \mathbb{P} (B_1 ,B_2)} &= \frac{7}{12} \cdot \frac{9}{14} \cdot \frac{5}{16} \cdot \frac{7}{18}
\end{align*}

and so on for the remaining 3 quantities.

However, I realize that these sets do not form a partition of our sample space (Edit, they do. I mistakenly thought that $B_1 B_2$ was a union of event, not an intersection, even though the interpretation was as an intersection for the rest of the time. Now $(B_1 \cap B_2) \cap (B_1 \cap W_2) = \emptyset$.

If I am on the right track, a leading hint would be more appreciated than a complete solution!

Comment: Looks all right to me: your events $B_2B_1$, $B_2W_1$, $W_2B_1$, $W_2W_1$ do partition the sample space.

Comment: The law of total probability has multiplying factors in it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: @DWD Right, that was an oversight. We should weight each conditional probability. I'll edit the problem before I embarrass myself!

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

From Blitzstein, page 54:

> Bayes' rule with extra conditioning, provided that $P(A,E)>0$ and $P(B,E)>0$ 
>   $$P(A|B,E)=\frac{P(B|A,E)P(A|E)}{P(B|E)}$$
>   Law of total probability with extra conditioning.  Let $A_1, ...,A_n$ be a partition on S. Provided that $P(A_i,E)>0$ for all i, we have
>   $$P(B|E)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}P(B|A_i,E)P(A_i|E)$$

Notice the denominator of the first eqn, this relates to your concern on the formation of a partition.  Let $A=(B_1,B_2)$ and extend the existing B and C to your $W_4$ and $W_3$ respectively.

$$P(B_1,B_2|W_4,W_3)=\frac{P(W_4|B_1,B_2,W_3)P(B_1,B_2|W_3)}{P(W_4|W_3)}$$

$$P(W_4|W_3)=\sum P(W_4|[B_1,B_2]_i,W_3)P([B_1,B_2]_i|W_3)$$
Here let the sum and subscripted square brackets denote the possible colours the balls one and two take.

Apply more Bayes' rule to this